# Export sqlplus query result to CSV with Export-CSV

Tags: powershell, sqlplus

I am running some queries in SQLPLUS inside Powershell 2.0

I am wanting to output the content of a table to csv using Export-CSV. 
It looks something like this.

```
$query = "set hea off`n"

$date1 = "ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),-3))"

$query += "DROP TABLE CHRIS_TEMP;CREATE TABLE CHRIS_TEMP AS SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLES;
exit;"

$sqlexec = ($query | sqlplus -s login/pass@db)

$sqlexec

$export= ("set wrap off 
set linesize 30000
select * from CHRIS_TEMP;" | sqlplus -s login/pass@db ) 
$export | Export-Csv   c:\users\*****\test.csv -notypeinformation
```

But the output is all one single field.
Can anyone help with this issue? I would prefer not to spool out CSV in sqlplus.

Comment: What does the `$export` look like when printed on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is without separators Powershell has no idea how your data is structured.  As soon as you add the comma, it becomes very easy to handle.

Otherwise, you are back to attempting to parse the data, since a blank column is not going to look much different then trailing spaces.

Using a direct connection to the database will give you more flexibility then using SQL plus. Your data will be in a structured record you can do what you want with.

When I **do** use SQLPlus inside a powershell script, I write the SQL Script programatically using file fragments to simplify the code, and send that to sqlplus rather then pipe the SQL itself to SQLPLUS.  This makes it easy to add such commands as
colsep , 
and other formatting commands.

Comment: I switched to direct connect and and filled a table  worked like a charm, exported using nimizen's metheod above. You both helped me a great deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this right now but try piping your $export to Select-Object:

```
$export | 
    Select-Object Column1, Column2, etc | 
    Export-Csv   c:\users\*****\test.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, this outputs a CSV with only the headers. However I combined it with the answer from marceljg and was able to get what I needed by dropping the SQLPLUS portion and direct connecting

Comment: Thanks for feeding back about your solution, glad this helped!